# How can I move to the bottom of a document using the pico editor?

Tags: editors

How can I move to the bottom of a document using the pico editor? <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd> is next page; is there a similar key for last page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL+_</kbd> and instead of entering a line number hit <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>.

Comment: How do you place those "buttons" into your answer?

Comment: `<kbd>CTRL+_</kbd>` - I have been wondering myself :)

Comment: @Chris You can see sources by clicking the edited link ( [this source](http://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/656069b1-8efd-4378-8520-7af9c1330639/view-source) )

Comment: @Michael: Unless you don't yet have edit privileges.

Comment: Or Ctrl-_ Ctrl-y to go to the top.

Comment: @Dennis No, the edited link still shows up (it's just above my gravatar, "edited X hours ago"). If the post hasn't been edited you can still get to the revision list, but you have to do it manually since there's no link; you go to http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/POST_ID/revisions

Comment: @Michael: Oh the editED link! I guess I should check into some literacy classes.